# Execute button in PowerPoint by excel VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to get Excel to execute a button in a custom ribbon I have in PowerPoint.

[The button is the one circled in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9TCT.png)

This is the code I have so far. So next step is to execute the ribbon button by VBA code.

Can anyone help?

```
Sub PPTXupdate()
Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oPPTSlide As PowerPoint.slide

Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue

Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(Filename:="\\Example\file.pptx")

End Sub
```

Comment: You kinda have the right idea but you're a little backwards. What you've done is create another instance of PowerPoint from inside PowerPoint. If your button and code are both in PowerPoint then you need to create an instance of Excel from your code in PowerPoint.  That would be like using PowerPoint to call Excel to call PowerPoint.   If you put that code and that button in Excel then you stand a good chance of starting a PowerPoint project from Excel.

Comment: Went another route, thank you!